# How can I play audio in the background but delayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I want to let audio play in the background, but I don't want it to start while 
the page loads. Can I delay it with CSS or JS? Is this possible?

I now got this, but it still doesn't work. I think it is supposed to work. 
Google Chrome shouldn't matter either right?

```
<audio id="audioID"
  src="spraakbericht.m4a"
style="display:none/*or you can use visibility:hidden*/"></audio>

<script>
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioID");
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    myAudio.play();
    }, 3000); // you can change this... whatever you want //
  }
</script>
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: Yeah, with javascript - this might help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: use setTimeout function. this will help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can easily achieve the same using some JS.

- Place audio div tag somewhere in your page. ex- div id="audio"
- Execute code when you want like on button click or automatically after 30 sec or 2 minutes using setTimeout.
  setTimeout( () => {
  document.getElementById('song').innerHTML = 'audio id="audio-player" controls="controls" style="display: none" src="media/Blue Browne.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"';
  }, (millisecond));

Note to add markup tag as I removed in the example as it's not supporting here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can use `setTimeout function` like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 3000)">
  <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

For background audio:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioID");
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
   myAudio.play();
  }, 3000);
}
```

**EDIT** Here is a working example for you:

```html
<audio id="audioID"
      src="http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_leltkjNwWL1qf32t9o1.mp3"
    style="display:none/*or you can use visibility:hidden*/"></audio>

<script>
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioID");
  window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      myAudio.play();
    }, 3000); // you can change this... whatever you want //
  }
</script>
```

Comment: And I don't want the audio to be visible? can I do this with hidden?

Comment: @Liesanne you can use `visibility:hidden` style for audio. And yes, it's compatible with browsers *(except mobile browsers...because there is no way to get autoplay working in mobile browsers. this is not allowed)*

Comment: Allright, It just won't autoplay.. I edited the post to my recent code

Comment: I have set the delay time to 3 seconds. You can change it how you want...

Comment: Thanks, I see! It just won't work.. There is no audio coming out.. Is it supposed to go in the head? I did use an m.4a file but that shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Ok, so it sometimes work.. Not every time. That is weird